# Oracle sql fiding shipping delay

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, top-n

can i know how i could write the sql statement in listing the shipping city and state for the order that has the longest shipping delay. I not sure need use the function Max in where

Comment: Please provide the structure of the tables concerned. Also provide the SQL you have tried so far.

Comment: Why was this question closed? I found it rather clear. Sure, it could be improved with details, but hey - we can assume things, can't we?

Comment: Yup, but not sure y dey do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your data structure is flat, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  ...
  shipping_city VARCHAR2(100),
  shipping_state VARCHAR2(100),
  shipping_delay NUMBER(7),
  ...
);
```

You can now write:

```
SELECT
  MAX(shipping_city)  KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY shipping_delay),
  MAX(shipping_state) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY shipping_delay)
FROM
  orders
```

Answer (score 0):

test table:

```
create table orders
(id int
,state varchar2(30)
,city varchar2(30)
,delay int);
```

test data:

```
insert into orders(id, state, city, delay)
select rownum as id, owner as state, table_name as city, abs(dbms_random.random) as delay
  from all_tables;
```

the query:

```
select * from (
select o.*, row_number() over (order by delay desc) pos from orders o
) where pos = 1
```